# jQuery: Selecting Previous Element from Click Event In Loop

Tags: jquery

Forgive me if this question has been asked before but I am new to jQuery and am having trouble even describing my problem. I have a loop in a php page that looks something like this:

```
foreach ($blahs as $blah) {
    echo '<p class="title">'.$blah->title.'</p>';
    echo '<input/>';
    echo '<input/>';
    echo '<div class="delete-button"><img /></div>';
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is the replacement of `.$blah->title.` with the phrase "Delete this title?" in the closest preceding `<p>` element to whichever `<div class="delete-button">` is clicked. To do this I have some jQuery at the top of the page like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".delete-button").click(function() {
            jQuery(this).prev('.title').html("Delete this title?");
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, this does not work. If I remove the `.prev('.title')` it replaces the html of the div so I know its working on some level but I cannot manage to get it to replace the html of the previous `<p class="title">`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: so what basically do you want to happen? don't be another [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take it a step further by wrapping all the items in a common parent and attach a *single handler* to the parent using `.on()` instead of assigning a handler per button. it's a performance benefit to only have a single handler as opposed to having `X` number of handlers for `X` items in the list.

also, seeing the structure of your items, let's wrap them. it prevents all items from being siblings (thus making an item distinct). then we can just use the `.sibling()` method to find the title relative to the button.

also, better use lists, they are more semantic.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d6Vny/3/)

```
<ul class="items">
    <li>    
        <p class="title">Blah title</p>
        <input/><input/>
        <div class="delete-button">Delete Button</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="title">Blah title</p>
        <input/><input/>
        <div class="delete-button">Delete Button</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="title">Blah title</p>
        <input/><input/>
        <div class="delete-button">Delete Button</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

​

```
$(function(){

    //add a single handler to the parent instead of per button
    $('.items').on('click','.delete-button',function(){
        //the "this" in here is the delete button element
        //since the button and .title are siblings, use the sibling method
        $(this).siblings('.title').text('Delete this title?');       
    });
});​
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for the elaborate answer and thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your related elements in their own div, as per this example: http://jsfiddle.net/d6Vny/2/

You will find that it works if your HTML is:

```
<div>    
    <p class="title">Blah title</p>
    <input/><input/>
    <div class="delete-button">Delete Button</div>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="title">Blah title</p>
    <input/><input/>
    <div class="delete-button">Delete Button</div>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="title">Blah title</p>
    <input/><input/>
    <div class="delete-button">Delete Button</div>
</div>
```

And your jQuery is:

```
jQuery(".delete-button").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).siblings('.title').html("Delete this title?");
});​
```

Answer (score -2):

use `$(this).prev().prev().prev()`

but it is 100% bound to your structure!

Comment: totally true, you should check the definition instead of giving downvotes: "Get the ***immediately*** preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector."

Comment: `.closest()` will go up one or more levels in the DOM hierarchy, looking for ancestors that match the selector and stopping as soon as it finds one. If title is an ancestor of `this`, it will work. But in the sample it does not seem to be an ancestor.